# how to implement mediaelement.js facebook video

Tags: mediaelement.js

how to implement facebook video using  mediaelement.js

how i done is :

```
<video type="video/facebook" src="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/"
                              class="mejs__player"
                              id="fb"
                              data-mejsoptions='{"alwaysShowControls": "true", "stretching": "responsive"}'>

                          </video>
```

in js :

```
$('#fb').mediaelementplayer({
    renderers: ['facebook'],
    success: function(player, node) {
        console.log("fb success");

    }
  });
```